# Wrong Min value returned from list - MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access to store data that looks like this :

**|EmpID    |Day1     |Day2     |Day3     |Day4    |Day5

|aa            |23        |23               |24                 |25             |

|bbb         |23              |1440    |                       |                      |            
|ccc            |                       |240              |240         |300         |360

|ddd           |                  |20            |20              |20           |20**

I found a way to find the Minimum value ACROSS the record (least number in the columns Day 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 in a single ROW) and wrote the below query :

***SELECT Minimum([Day1],[Day2],[Day3],[Day4],[Day5],[Day6],[Day7],[Day8],[Day9],[Day10],[Additional]) as [MinVal], Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5 from Tasks;***

to get this result :

**MinVal |Day1     |Day2    |Day3    |Day4   |Day5

23           |23            |23           |24           |25           |

5                |23            |1440      |5              |                |

80           |                 |240       |80            |300        |360

10           |                |20             |10              |20           |20**

Now I'm trying to get the minimum value from the MinVal column. 
**Expected:** 5

 **Actual:** 10

The query I am using is : 
**Select min([MinVal]) as MinimumVal from ( *SELECT Minimum([Day1],[Day2],[Day3],[Day4],[Day5],[Day6],[Day7],[Day8],[Day9],[Day10],[Additional]) as [MinVal] from Tasks*) t ;**

The data type for all fields is number.
I cannot figure out why the Min function is returning the wrong value from the list. Please help me figure this out!

**Edit :** I got the Minimum function from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209857) . I had to make changes to the function given in the page because if your record has null values and only one number, it would give null as output ( does not handle comparing NULL to a number correctly). **So, instead of :** 
 If FieldArray(I) < currentVal Then
 currentVal = FieldArray(I)
 End If 

 **Use :**

If (FieldArray(I) < currentVal) And (IsNull(currentVal) = False) Then
 currentVal = FieldArray(I)
 ElseIf (IsNull(currentVal) = True) And (IsNull(FieldArray(I)) = False) Then
 currentVal = FieldArray(I)
 End If

Comment: whats the data type of columns Day1,2...etc

Comment: Sorted alphabetically `10` comes before `5`, so I would guess that it's returning a string value.

Comment: Did you write a function named 'Minimum'? There is no function by that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the minimum function (found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209857)) that you are using to compute the minimum value across the fields might not return the number/int data type. So convert your minval column to a number and then do a min..

```
 Select min(val([MinVal])) as MinimumVal from 
        ( SELECT Minimum([Day1],[Day2],[Day3],[Day4],[Day5],[Day6],[Day7],
        [Day8],[Day9],[Day10],[Additional]) as [MinVal] from Tasks) t ;
```

Comment: Thank you @cableload. This works perfectly. I changed the data type of currentVal (in the Minimum function) to integer but still didn't work. Good learning today.